# 'R animation' displaying only static image instead of animation

Tags: r, animation

I am new to R animation package. I have installed `ImageMagick` version `7.0.7-Q16`. I am working in `RStudio` in a Windows `7 64-bit` environment.

While I am trying to code my first animation with simpler one.

Below code:

```
  ani.options(convert = 'C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\\convert.exe')
 saveGIF({
for (i in 1:10) plot(runif(10), ylim = 0:1)
   })
```

Here I am getting the following result:

```
Output at: animation.gif
[1] TRUE
```

I have also tried this same code in other way i.e. I have replaced `convert.exe` with `magick.exe`:

```
ani.options(convert=shortPathName("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\\magick.exe"))
saveGIF({
for (i in 1:10) plot(runif(10), ylim = 0:1)
})
```

Here I am getting same output. i.e.

```
Output at: animation.gif
[1] TRUE
```

Question:

In both case it is displaying only the Image on the screen. The animation is not running. Am I missing something? Suggestion is always appreciated.

Comment: So you are opening 'animation.gif' in a program that displays gifs properly I assume? You aren't just looking at the R plot window?

Comment: @thelatemail, Yes, the displaying gifs is properly. No I am not looking at the R plot window. I want animation start to be play automatically.

Comment: For the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/yihui/animation/issues/116

Answer (score -1):

@Yuihui. Thanks. I just have to change my default photo viewer from  "Picasa photo viewer" to chrome or Firefox. After that my animation is working fine. for details https://github.com/yihui/animation/issues/116